# Is there a solution for ImportError when trying to import Destination from PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pypdf

I am working in Python and trying to import the Destination class from PyPDF2 using 'from PyPDF2.pdf import Destination' and I keep getting an error 'ImportError: cannot import name 'Destination' from 'PyPDF2''. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Comment: Also, have you tried just searching the package for "class Destination"? Doing that would have been quicker than writing this question.

Answer (score 1):

> I am working in Python and trying to import the Destination class from PyPDF2 using 'from PyPDF2.pdf import Destination' and I keep getting an error 'ImportError: cannot import name 'Destination' from 'PyPDF2''. Any help would be appreciated.

Remove `.pdf` from your import.

```
from PyPDF2 import Destination
```

Comment: Kicks a different error 'ImportError: cannot import name 'Destination' from 'PyPDF2''